# Swift tableView with 3 Prototype Cells and auto-height

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a concept which I want to realize in Xcode. Its a default  TableViewController with 3 Prototype cells.

```
Cell 1 = name (Prototype Pages)
Cell 2 = seperator (Prototype Seperator)
Cell 3 = only ImageView (Prototype Seperator-with-only-image)
```

Cell 1 and cell 2 is OK. I need to set the height of all "Prototype Seperator-with-only-image" cells to auto. The height should be calculated based on added image dimensions.

Here my mockup

[image]

Addional info: The "Prototype Seperator-with-only-image" can occur multiple times and the dimensions of the images can vary.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tableview's `rowHeight` equal to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    self.yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 42.0
```

Here you are telling your `tableview` to calculate the dimension of the `row`.
Then you are saying that you estimate that the `row` will have a height of 42, basically setting a minimum height.

I think [this](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/) is a great example using a demo app.